# Создание объекта из строки имени класса

Tags: python

Как создать объект получив имя класса из строки (класс находится в другом модуле)?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы загрузить модуль динамически и создать объект из строки:

```
import importlib

modulename, dot, classname = "pkg.your_module.ClassName".rpartition('.')
module = importlib.import_module(modulename)
klass = getattr(module, classname)
instance = klass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб, то сделал бы так:

## testClass.py

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = "Hello, TestClass!"
```

## testImport.py

```
moduleName = "testClass"
className = "TestClass"
exec("from " + moduleName + " import " + className)
exec("fileObject =" + className + "()")
print fileObject.name
```

## Тест

```
>>> python testImport.py
>>> Hello, TestClass!
```

Но это быдло код, имхо.
Вообще посмотрел бы на другие реализации, думал много раз систему плагинов для своей программы написать.

Comment: Да. Не очень.

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226330/instantiate-a-python-class-from-a-name  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Comment: Fike, спасибо.

Comment: Fike, спасибо.